# Scraping Multiple IMDB Movie Cast List using RVEST in R

Tags: r, rvest, imdb

I have a list of 1000 movie URLs that link to the Cast/Crew page for IMDB. I need to figure out how to scrape all of those pages for the entire cast and crew and want to create a three column table with the information.

Column A would contain the movie name, Column B would contain the release year, and Column C would contain the actor. The end goal would be to join it with my main movie dataset off the movie name and year for more efficient querying.

Originally, I pulled this data with my main movie set but all the cast members got dumped into a single list in the column and I cannot figure out how to break this apart in excel.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

[image]

The idea behind the below code would be to create two tables - one would be the main movie table with name, year, director, etc and the other would be the above-described table.

Does anyone have any clue how I can write this movie_cast list to produce its own table like the one in the image?

```
library(rvest) #webscraping package
library(dplyr) #piping 
library(stringr)

get_cast = function(movie_link2) {
  movie_page = read_html(movie_link2)
  movie_name = movie_page %>% html_nodes(".parent a") %>%  html_text() 
  movie_cast = movie_page %>% html_nodes(".loadlate , .primary_photo+ td a") %>%  html_text() %>%  paste(movie_name, "-", .) 
  movie_cast <- movie_cast[!movie_cast %in% c("" )]
  gsub('[\t\n]', '', movie_cast)
  
  movie_cast
  
  return(movie_cast)
}

movies = data.frame()
movie_cast = data.frame()


for (page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 10)) {
  
  link = paste("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls006266261/?st_dt=&mode=detail&page=", page_result, "&ref_=ttls_vm_dtl&sort=list_order,asc", sep ="")
  
  page = read_html(link)
  
  name <- page %>% rvest::html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>% rvest::html_text()
  name <- name[!name %in% c(" Screen Two")]
  
  movie_link = html_node(html_nodes(page, '.lister-item-content'),".lister-item-header a") %>%  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.imdb.com", .,  sep="")
  movie_link2 <- file.path(dirname(movie_link), "fullcredits", str_replace(basename(movie_link), "ttls_li_tt", "tt_ql_cl"))
  
  year <-html_node(html_nodes(page, '.lister-item-content'),".text-muted.unbold") %>% html_text()
  year <- year[!year %in% c("IMDb user rating (average)","Number of votes","Release year or range")]
  
  rating <-html_node(html_nodes(page, '.lister-item-content'),".certificate") %>% html_text()
  
  director <- html_node(html_nodes(page, '.lister-item-content'),".text-small a:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
  director <- director[!director %in% c("gibboanx" )]
  
  gross <- html_node(html_nodes(page, '.lister-item-content'),".ghost~ .text-muted+ span") %>% html_text()
  gross <- gross[!gross %in% c("|"  )]
  
  meta <- html_node(html_nodes(page, '.lister-item-content'), '.ratings-metascore span') %>% html_text()
  
  genre <- html_node(html_nodes(page, '.lister-item-content'),".genre") %>% html_text() 
  
  cast = sapply(movie_link2, FUN = get_cast, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  
  movies <- rbind(movies, data.frame(name, year, rating, director, gross, meta, genre, stringsasfactors = FALSE))
  movie_cast <- cbind(movie_cast,cast)
  
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))  
}
```

Comment: First standardize the code  for one movie and then use `for` loop to get all others

Comment: And you are going against the terms and services of IMDB. They have an [API](https://imdb-api.com/API) available for getting this kind of data. There is even a [package on cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imdbapi/index.html).